# Is extra whitespace allowed inside htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Can I add extra spaces or tab characters inside the `.htaccess` file?

For instance:

```
Redirect /foo/foo.php                           /faa/faa.php
```

Comment: Should be no problem. Did you give it a try …?

Comment: Seems to work okay, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to add in extra whitespace into a HTACCESS file.

You can also add in comments via the use of a hashtag.

Here's a quick example from something I worked on recently

```
###########################
# === PHP Apache Module ===
###########################

<IfModule mod_php.c>
    php_value post_max_size         48M
    php_value memory_limit          512M
    php_value max_execution_time    600
    php_value max_input_vars        1000
    php_value max_input_time        360
    php_value upload_max_filesize   32M
</IfModule>
```

The extra tabs at the start of the IF Module makes it much more readable.

The tabs at the end between the property and the value are also valid.

To add to this it'll work for CSP properties if you want to multi-line it

```
# BEGIN Content-Security-Policy 
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "\
        default-src https:; \
        font-src    https: data:; \
        img-src     https: data: 'self'; \
    "
</IfModule>
```